# ASP.NET - A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected

Tags: asp.net

On a windows 2008 web server, I get the following error whenever posting a form containing html tags in textboxes:

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (widget$txtText="

This is a common error and you fix it by either doing Page ValidateRequest = false or in the web.config with pages validaterequest = false. However, on this specific server, it completely ignores the validaterequest = false and throws this exception anyway. Has anyone seen this behavior before and know what else I can do to prevent this error? I've seen it in 2 web apps now on the same server, it's really weird.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don;t know about 3.5 but to fix it in 4.0 use

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

in your web.config and set the page directive as you said in your question.

Comment: Wow thanks, for some reason it set up the DefaultAppPool as using ASP.NET 4 so the app that was supposed to be using 2 was still ignoring the validaterequest attributes.

Answer (score 0):

What version of .NET are you running? Page validation works a little differently in .NET 4.